# syslog filling with radeon_crtc_page_flip_target

Tags: graphics, radeon

ASROCK MOBO AMD Athlon II X4 630 Processor with added AMD VISIONTEK Cedar Radeon HD 5000 graphics card.

Issue is that syslog fills with `drm:radeon_crtc_page_flip_target [radeon]] flip-ioctl()` regardless user action. It is mostly annoying but has some secondary impacts. There is an similar old bug on this from 2015.

Question 1, how can I supress the messages in syslog/kernel log.

Question 2, should I raise a kernel bug?

```
Linux SAL9000 5.4.0-89-generic #100-Ubuntu SMP x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cedar [Radeon HD 5000/6000/7350/8350 Series] [1002:68f9] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: VISIONTEK Cedar [Radeon HD 5000/6000/7350/8350 Series] [1545:5450]
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR+ FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
```

Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Thanks for your support

Comment: Try increasing frame buffer rate in your BIOS.  Back in 2015 that was what could fix this problem. If that is not possible or not a solution file a bug report at http://bugs.freedesktop.org/ with product DRI, component DRM/Radeon It is a hardware/driver issue we can not fix :)

Comment: "how can I supress the messages in syslog/kernel log" rsyslog does it like this: https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/filters.html

Comment: bug filed #1949301.